# Unity, WCF and Windows services

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-services, unity-container

Does anyone have a good example of using Unity and WCF from within a Windows service? There are no shortage of articles on using IIS to self-host the service, but not for Windows services. I've been following Rory Primrose's articles on [integrating Unity and WCF](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/15/Unity-dependency-injection-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-1.aspx), which I would say are quite definitive, but even his examples only go as far as using in ASP.NET (for instance, his UnityServiceHost is internal and cannot be instantiated directly, except through the UnityServiceHostFactory, but there's nothing to show how to use the factory outside of ASP.NET. In the end, I made my UnityServiceHost public (actually, it's a UnityWebServiceHost, but that's beside the point).

I've followed this posting on [using Unity with .NET services](http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=31035), but again, it doesn't go the complete distance for my needs. Is there anyone else out there who has encountered this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fabio/archive/2009/03/24/inversion-of-control-with-wcf-and-unity.aspx) you have example with self hosting. When working with self hosting you don't need any `ServiceHostFactory` - it is only for IIS based hosting so your `ServiceHost` implementation must be public and you have to provide Unity container into the service host and instancing behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the link; the implementation is pretty similar to Rory's (although the implementation of UnityServiceBehavior's ApplyDispatchBehavior is better as it checks for IMetadataExchange); however, it doesn't cover specifically how to integrate it all with Unity in a .NET Service, but rather as a console application.